# What is the difference between using add and finalize in rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Both of these code snippets seem to have the same effect:

1. add

   ```
   this.test$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe().add(() => console.log('added'));
   ```
2. finalize

   ```
   this.test$.pipe(take(1), finalize(() => console.log('finalized'))).subscribe();
   ```

Is using one preferable over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add` has more purpose than that, it allows you to append subscription so that a single `unsubscribe` will also unsubscribe all appended subscriptions.

```
const subscription = observable1.subscribe(x => console.log('first: ' + x));
const childSubscription = observable2.subscribe(x => console.log('second: ' + x));
 
subscription.add(childSubscription);
 
setTimeout(() => {
  // Unsubscribes BOTH subscription and childSubscription
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: also finalize allows you to add some finalization logic to an observable in scope of code that may be far separated from the place that observable get subscribed so it allows for keeping code compartmentalized and close to where it makes sense